# How to send json from nodejs server to client js file using Express and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, express

I am new to Nodejs and Express and want to search some results from mongoDB and show it on client browser, i can find the values from the mongoDB query but not able to send it to client js file,
It says doc is not defined, any help will be appreciated.

```
***app.js(Server)***
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = "8001";
var mongo= require('mongodb');
var mongoClient=mongo.MongoClient;
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/home', function(req, res) {
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/views/index.html");
});

app.listen(port, function() {
console.log("Server running at:" + port);
})

app.post("/response", function(req, res) {
var t = req.body;
mongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/query", function(err,db){
cursor =db.collection('response').find({"name1":t.text},{"name2":1, "_id":0});
   cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
      if (doc != null) {
       console.log(doc);

      }

   });

})
res.send(doc);
});


***index.js(Client Side)***
$.ajax({
url: '/response',
type:"POST",
contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
  complete: function(data) {
  console.log(data.responseText);
  alert(data.responseText);
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`doc` is a variable local to your closure and therefore not available when you call res.send(doc).

In addition to that, you are iterating over all of your documents.  You need to choose which one to return.

I recommend something like this:

```
cursor = db.collection('response').find({"name1":t.text},{"name2":1, "_id":0});
cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
   if (doc != null) {
       console.log(doc);
       return res.json(doc); // return the first document found
   }
});
```

Also note:

- you should sanitize your data before passing it into the query
- you shouldn't connect to the database on each request, instead set up mongo in the application context
- you should check `err` to see if mongo returned an error before trying to iterate the cursor

**EDIT:**

To be more specific, the whole block should look like this:

```
app.post("/response", function (req, res) {
    var t = req.body;
    mongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/query", function (err, db) {
        if (err) {
            return res.json(err);
        }

        db.collection('tweets').findOne({"name1": t.text}, {"name2": 1, "_id": 0}, function (err, doc) {
            if (doc != null) {
                console.log(doc);
                return res.json(doc);
            }
            return res.sendStatus(404);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: appreciate the points mentioned, but still it shoes same error because "doc" is not in the scope, any other way around?

Comment: @jaideepsingh is your doc being printed to the console?

Comment: Yes, it is being printed on console

Comment: yes tried with the updated code too, still cant get around with the errors- have a look: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxjv4gdaEEAENG1HRGF2WUMwaWM/view?usp=sharing, and at index.js it says "NOT FOUND"

Comment: apologies -- the issue you were facing was that the .each call was not exiting.  I updated my answer with a findOne() example.

Answer (score 1):

#### A few things:

- `cursor.each()` has been deprecated in favour of `cursor.forEach()` assuming you're running a recent version of mongo
- Your first line in a callback should be something like `if (err) { console.error(err) }` - at this point you'd probably see that your query is invalid:
- Your query should probably look like `.find({'name1': t.text, 'name2': 1, '_id': 0})`
- If you are referencing an auto-generated mongo ObjectID as `_id`, you have to use `'_id': new mongo.ObjectID(<whatever string holds the _id>)` in order for it to work. If you didn't specify an `_id` on creation, the automatically generated ObjectID will require this.
- The [mongo docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/index.html) are great, highly recommend leafing through them for examples and which bits take which arguments and the options for all of them.
- Consider using promises instead of callbacks to help tidy up. It's really easy with mongo - you just don't specify a callback function, and instead tack a `.then(document => { ... })` on the end, and a single `.catch(err => {console.error(err)})` will catch errors at the db, collection and cursor levels.
- With jQuery, consider using `.done(result => {...})` and `.fail(err => { ... })` (aka promises) instead of `complete` for your ajax calls, and whatever you do, don't forget to attach an error handler. (I'm not even sure 'complete' is the right property, might depend on which jQuery you're using)
- If you're doing an AJAX `POST` you should probably attach some `data` (and a `dataType`)to it. Otherwise you'll still get no records because `req.body` will be undefined or empty.
- In the case of an error, you should be responding with `res.status(500); res.end()` at a minimum so you can tell when something has gone wrong on the server end.
- To help along, `console.log(req.body)` right at the top of your function so you know what data is arriving.
- Finally, if you intend on responding with JSON - use `res.json(doc)` instead of `res.send(doc)`